# how to change useraccountcontrol attribute from 544 to 512 by ldap java

Tags: java, ssl, active-directory, ldap, tls1.2

javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 53 - 0000052D: SvcErr: DSID-031A12E8, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0

```
 DirContext connection ;
        
        Properties env = new Properties();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://localhost:10389");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "uid=admin, ou=system");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "secret");
```

.
Whenever am creating user through Java code. the user is enable and passwordNOtRequited type. but i need to change this as a normal user account

Comment: Tell us what you have tried and show logs or results and the code where you change the attribute values. Are you setting this on creation or After creation?
I doubt that the values could be changed by a "normal user account".
and Read:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you mean that you need to change it *to* a normal user account.

When you create an account and don't set the password, [`userAccountControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/useraccountcontrol-manipulate-account-properties) has to be set either disabled (512 + 2), or password not required (512 + 32).

If you want a normal enabled account (512), you have to first set the password. The attribute for the password is [`unicodePwd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/6e803168-f140-4d23-b2d3-c3a8ab5917d2). It is a little tricky to set. There are two requirements:

1. The connection has to be encrypted. This can be by LDAPS (LDAP over SSL).
2. The password value must be enclosed in double quotes and encoded in UTF-16.

There is an example [here of how to do it in Java](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Example%20-%20Active%20Directory%20Change%20Password%20JNDI):

```
String quotedPassword = "\"" + password + "\"";
char unicodePwd[] = quotedPassword.toCharArray();
byte pwdArray[] = new byte[unicodePwd.length * 2];
for (int i = 0; i < unicodePwd.length; i++)
{
    pwdArray[i * 2 + 1] = (byte) (unicodePwd[i] >>> 8);
    pwdArray[i * 2 + 0] = (byte) (unicodePwd[i] & 0xff);
}
System.out.print("encoded password: ");
for (int i = 0; i < pwdArray.length; i++)
{
    System.out.print(pwdArray[i] + " ");
}
System.out.println();
ModificationItem[] mods = new ModificationItem[1];
mods[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute("UnicodePwd", pwdArray));
ldapContext.modifyAttributes("cn=" + username + BASE_NAME, mods);
```

You can modify this code to fit yours.

Comment: .pfx certificate got. can we import this certificate to java code without any conversions

Comment: The pfx is the private key? You don't need the private key. You just need to trust the root certificate. I'm not a Java developer, but there's an example of using LDAPS in Java here (note the `TRUST_STORE`): https://bitbucket.org/jwilleke/examples/src/91c2df9b5481b30e5ca213a7baa0ce7e0a04752c/Examples-JNDI/src/com/willeke/samples/ldap/jndi/ADConnection.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

Comment: Why this error javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: host:636 [Root exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection or outbound has closed]